# Querytable Post request

Tags: excel, vba, curl

I have a curl request

```
curl ‘link’ -H 'cookie: cfduid=1121213123123123123123123123; user-id=12312312; stack[hash]=1231231; stack[user]=123123123’  --data 'user-id=123123123&currencies%5Bmetal%5D=11&currencies%5Bkeys%5D=11&offers=1&buyout=1&promoted=0'
```

I want to do requests from excel, I found how I can do this without header(-h)

```
Sub PostExcel()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;link", Destination:=Range("P2"))
.PostText = "sku=11111111&price=1111&key=1111111111111"
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SaveData = True
.Refresh
End With
```

How can I add a header request in this code?